# Qt Creator refactoring and c++ templates

Tags: c++, qt, templates, qt-creator

I'd like to figure out: is there any ways to do refactoring with c++ template classes? I want to insert virtual functions of base class or specialized template quickly.

It's not problem if your class isn't big enough. But when you have 10 methods, that you need to override and specialize, it becomes routine and error prone.

For example, I have this code

```
template <typename T>
class MyTemplateInterface
{
public:
    virtual void DoWork() = 0;
};
```

Than I write that code

```
template <typename T>
class MyTemplateClass : public MyTemplateInterface<T>
{
public:
    MyTemplateClass() {}
};
```

And what I want to get is that

```
template <typename T>
class MyTemplateClass : public MyTemplateInterface<T>
{
public:
    MyTemplateClass() {}
    void DoWork() override
    {

    }
};
template<>
void MyTemplateClass<int>::DoWork()
{
    // specialized template
}
```

p.s. sorry for my broken English

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq15-academic.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The article says that Qt does not support templates, but I use pure C++ code. So can I suppose that if Qt doesn't support it, Qt Creator won't too? Maybe there is another simple way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want IDE to generate the proper virtual methods this is possible in Qt Creator. I'm not sure since which version this option is available. I'm using `Qt 4.1.0`.

Having the code you've specified you can right click the derived class name and select `Refactor > Insert Virtual Functions of Base Classes` like in the image below.

[image]

Then you can select different options on whether you want only a declaration or definition to be generated inside or outside the class.

This hopefully answers a part of your question. However I'm not sure if currently there is a way for semi-automatic generation of specializations.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using Qt Creator 4.3.1 and there is no "Insert Virtual Function of Base Classes" with templates, but I'm actively using that feature with classes without templates. Sure, it's partial answer of my question.